# MOSFET parasitic turn-on

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, mosfet-driver, gate-driving, parasitic-capacitance

I'm simulating a circuit which uses a high-voltage SiC N-channel FET to discharge a large voltage (something close to the breakdown voltage of the FET, 1.7 kV). The power supply for the circuit is a 1 A source.

The idea is that the voltage at the top of the circuit will increase as the current ramps up to 1 A through the load resistor (R5 = 100 kΩ) until pulses are sent through the transformer to turn on M1 allowing the voltage to fully discharge to ground.

What I am seeing in simulation is M1 turning on somehow before the gate is actively driven through the transformer (L2 and L3 are part of a transformer here). It appears that some current is going through the 10 MΩ resistor, and charging up the gate capacitance through the gate-drain capacitance Cdg. Is this what is actually happening here?

I made the resistor a very large value (10 MΩ) to slow down this charging of Cgs so it can be viewed here.

[image: Schematic]

Where can I read more about this type of parasitic turn-on (if that is what's happening here) and is there a way to exaggerate this affect to increase the voltage on the gate capacitance to drive the MOSFET even harder?

It is desirable in my application to have the FET turned on when power is first applied to the circuit, or as soon as possible after power is applied. I can't drive the FET through the transformer until the FET conducts > 50 mA Id.

The waveforms are:

- I(R1)
- V(n002) = voltage between R1 and FET U1 Drain
- V(m1_g) = Vgs of U1 FET

As you can see the Vgs of U1 is charged to 2.4 V and then rises again to 3.4 V. It seems there is some kind of self-regulation happening here, where once the FET has been parasitically charged above its Vth, some current can flow through the drain-source channel and so there is less current available to further charge the Cgs until the Id and Icdg find a balance.

I might be totally on the wrong track with my interpretation. Please enlighten me as to what is really happening in this circuit and where I can find more information about this.

[image: Waveforms]

Comment: Do you get the same issue when using one of LTspice’s built-in MOSFETs for your FETs? Are you actually going to ensure your case temperature is 1°C in real life, or is the voltage on `Tc` a mistake? What about `Tj`?  You shouldn’t leave it disconnected and put at least some kind of crude estimate to what your junction temperature might be.

Comment: Are V2 and V3 short circuited? What are they for? Also, 1A through 100kΩ is 100kV. The simulation doesn't show that much voltage, so are you sure this graph came from this version of the schematic?

Comment: Ste, Yes this still occurs with LTspice built-in MOSFETs. Andy, I literally labelled the relevant waveforms in the post. Simon, V2 and V3 are needed for the temperature pins of the SiC FET model. The simulation won't run unless Tc/Tj is connected to a voltage source. Yes I'm sure the waveforms are from this schematic, I'm just not showing the voltage at the Top net, above the 10Meg resistor. That voltage does get extremely high when the FET is OFF depending on the value of the load resistor (R5). But the simulation always starts out with the Vgs being charged, how is this happening?

Comment: @L30LVC I was trying to point out that you should connect voltage sources to `Tc` AND `Tj` which match the case temperatures and junction temperatures, respectively, of what you expect in real life on those FETs. The model requires these to function properly. Just hooking up a 1V source to one of them to "force" the simulation to run is not sufficient. This might not solve your current problem, but it should eventually be fixed. As for your current problem, I can try taking a look if you post the whole schematic so I can properly duplicate it. Or copy/paste the contents of your `.asc` file.